# How can I use Scala reflection to find the self type traits?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

```
trait Bar
trait Dar

trait Foo {  self : Bar with Dar =>

}

trait Child extends Foo
```

How do I use the new reflection API to go from typeOf[Foo] or typeOf[Child] to find out that its self type has Bar and Dar traits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_10).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Bar
trait Dar

trait Foo {  self : Bar with Dar =>

}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Bar
defined trait Dar
defined trait Foo

scala> val selfTypeOfFoo = typeOf[Foo].typeSymbol.asClass.selfType
selfTypeOfFoo: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Foo with Bar with Dar
```

If you want to inspect the self type further, you can match it against [`RefinedType`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types%24RefinedType):

```
scala> val RefinedType(parents, _) = selfTypeOfFoo
parents: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(Foo, Bar with Dar)

scala> val RefinedType(innerParents, _) = parents(1)
innerParents: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(Bar, Dar)
```

Comment: What is the typeSymbol is like this:  type _7 (of class scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$AbstractTypeSymbol)?   Calling asClass fails on this.